# TableView как сделать строки одинакового цвета

Tags: css, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу чтобы все строки были одинакового цвета, а не чередованием, как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант могу предложить следующие:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;

public class FilledTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setText(empty || item == null ? null : item.toString());

        TableRow tableRow = getTableRow();
        if ( tableRow != null ) {
            tableRow.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: green;");
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования (на любой из столбцов таблицы):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TableColumn<String [], String> tableColumn = new TableColumn();
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[0]));
        tableColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new FilledTableCell<>());

        TableColumn<String [], String> tableColumn1 = new TableColumn();
        tableColumn1.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[1]));

        TableColumn<String [], String> tableColumn2 = new TableColumn();
        tableColumn2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue()[2]));

        TableView<String []> tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumn, tableColumn1, tableColumn2);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new String [] {"1", "2", "3"}
                , new String []{"4", "5", "6"}
                , new String []{"7", "8", "9"}
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```